# How to extract specific text from a webpage

Tags: web-scraping

I am interested in finding patterns of constellations. I am using 'Sky map' android app for visual inspection, now I want to build an app to find similar constellation structures. A sub-problem of that is to find the coordinates for specific celestial objects.

Example: How can I obtain the coordinates of 'Moon' at a given time,date and location.

https://theskylive.com/planetarium provides this information on their webpage in following manner.

```
 Object: Moon [info|live][less]
 Right Asc: 04h 15m 12.5s **Decl: 17° 05' 46.3"** (J2000) [HMS|Dec]
 Magnitude: -10.54 Altitude: 56° Solar Elongation: 100.4° Constellation: Ari 
 Sun distance: 147.77 Million Km Earth distance: 0.38 Million Km
 Rise: 10:48 Transit: 18:40 Set: 01:35 **Europe/London**
```

For Moon we can find coordinates using the webpage, Is there some API? or How can we do it by extracting coordinate information from the web page.

Comment: Do you plan to extract this data in the Android app on in some preparation stage on the PC?

Comment: Yeah I want to extract this data in an android app. Is there something wrong in my question, it has got 2 downvotes.

Comment: I do not know about downvotes, sorry. Maybe the readers think there are not enough details in the post about planned implementation.

Comment: What details I shall add? I will do for sure.

Comment: I am not a mobile programmer, but maybe some details about supported OS versions, frameworks you plan to use would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but here is a python implementation to it. You'd have to figure out the accepted location parameters, but date, hour, and minute are all there:

```
import requests

url = 'https://theskylive.com/planetariumdata'

params = {
'obj': 'moon',
'h': '10',
'm': '30',
'date': '2019-02-28',
'localdata': '51.48|0|Greenwich, United Kingdom|Europe/London'}

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

print (response['objects']['moon'])
```

**Output:**

```
{'status': True, 'utc_time': 1551349800, 'ar': 18.114288194444, 'dec': -21.301003146701, 'mag': '-9.11', 'distsun': 148031243.76562, 'distearth': 399053.81054688, 'constell': 'Oph', 'sot': 292.2907375, 'lastdate': '2019-Feb-28 00:00', 'hlong': '158.9866', 'hlongRad': 2.7748396365512, 'hlat': '0.0060', 'hlatRad': 0.00010471975511966, 'hx': -0.92639216172362, 'hy': 0.34779595586615, 'hz': 8.4403227939488e-05, 'elongation': '67.7', 'altitude': 7.7566655880485, 'id': 'moon', 'name': 'Moon', 'category': 'planets', 'circumstances': {'visibility': 'partial', 'raise': 3.0419974882059, 'set': 11.875359660362, 'transit': 7.4771821984014, 'raise_ut': 1551322951.191, 'set_ut': 1551354751.2948, 'transit_ut': 1551338917.8559, 'transit_height': 17.341269275926, 'azimuth_rise': 110.98610232928, 'azimuth_set': 248.66063774998, 'LSTr': 13.552197907652, 'LSTs': 22.409745024956, 'GSTr': 13.552197907652, 'GSTs': 22.409745024956, 'raise_local': 3.0419974882059, 'set_local': 11.875359660362, 'transit_local': 7.4771821984014}, 'timezone': 'Europe/London', 'age': 23}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not an Android expert, but this is what you can do in

**build.gradle**

```scala
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'test.test'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180813'
}
```

**Planetarium.java**

```java
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Planetarium {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    JSONObject get(String... objects) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder("https://theskylive.com/planetariumdata?");

        // Current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
        urlBuilder.append("date=").append(dateFormat.format(new Date()));

        // add url query string for all objects
        for (String obj : objects) {
            // URL encoded aobj[] => aobj%5B%5D=
            urlBuilder.append("&").append("aobj%5B%5D=").append(obj);
        }

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(urlBuilder.toString())
                .build();

        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            String json = response.body().string();
            return new JSONObject(json);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Planetarium planetarium = new Planetarium();
        JSONObject response = planetarium.get("moon", "mars");
        System.out.println(response.toString(2));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{
  "utc_seconds": 1551816600,
  "utc_timestamp": "201903052010",
  "objects": {
    "moon": {
      "distsun": 1.479847408587E8,
      "altitude": -32.421642244539,
      "dec": -12.501182812768,
      "constell": "Cap",
      "timezone": "Europe/London",
      "hlat": "-0.0075",
      "hlong": "163.9072",
      "elongation": "9.6",
      "lastdate": "2019-Mar-05 00:00",
      "hx": -0.95427043393163,
      "hy": 0.26061067578779,
      "mag": "-4.82",
      "hlongRad": 2.8607203077248,
      "hz": -1.6343451194632E-4,
      "utc_time": 1551816600,
      "distearth": 405722.20937018,
      "sot": 350.29647638889,
      "id": "moon",
      "circumstances": {
        "transit_local": 11.428494722983,
        "raise_ut": 1.5517668981849E9,
        "set": 16.623858118962,
        "raise_local": 6.3606069281934,
        "visibility": "partial",
        "azimuth_set": 256.90380469917,
        "LSTs": 3.4997935653561,
        "LSTr": 17.208442522882,
        "set_local": 16.623858118962,
        "azimuth_rise": 104.50312047906,
        "GSTs": 3.4997935653561,
        "GSTr": 17.208442522882,
        "transit_ut": 1.551785142581E9,
        "transit": 11.428494722983,
        "raise": 6.3606069281934,
        "set_ut": 1.5518038458892E9,
        "transit_height": 24.710020581601
      },
      "ar": 22.578738425926,
      "name": "Moon",
      "category": "planets",
      "hlatRad": -1.3089969389957E-4,
      "age": 27,
      "status": true
    },
    "mars": {
      "distsun": 2.2963710671492E8,
      "altitude": 27.808183248664,
      "circumstances": {
        "transit_local": 15.80120694427,
        "raise_ut": 1.5517741680418E9,
        "set": 23.222402283833,
        "raise_local": 8.3800116047075,
        "visibility": "partial",
        "azimuth_set": 286.34760861411,
        "LSTs": 10.11640394619,
        "LSTr": 19.233376146402,
        "set_local": 23.222402283833,
        "azimuth_rise": 73.652391385888,
        "GSTs": 10.11640394619,
        "GSTr": 19.233376146402,
        "transit_ut": 1.551800884345E9,
        "transit": 15.80120694427,
        "raise": 8.3800116047075,
        "set_ut": 1.5518276006482E9,
        "transit_height": 54.867608614112
      },
      "dec": 16.347608614112,
      "constell": "Ari",
      "timezone": "Europe/London",
      "hlat": "0.8142",
      "hlong": "75.6345",
      "elongation": "58.1",
      "lastdate": "2019-Mar-05 00:00",
      "hx": 0.36958631955143,
      "ar": 2.6748900462963,
      "hy": 1.4897081109635,
      "mag": "1.23",
      "hlongRad": 1.3200710530997,
      "hz": 0.022145899657793,
      "utc_time": 1551816600,
      "distearth": 2.704192732295E8,
      "name": "Mars",
      "sot": 58.1002,
      "id": "mars",
      "category": "planets",
      "hlatRad": 0.014210470769738,
      "status": true
    },
    "sun": {
      "distsun": 0,
      "altitude": -22.992657046501,
      "circumstances": {
        "transit_local": 12.176106019167,
        "raise_ut": 1.551767861711E9,
        "set": 17.739026911053,
        "raise_local": 6.6282530456618,
        "visibility": "partial",
        "azimuth_set": 263.93596334029,
        "LSTs": 4.618015588543,
        "LSTr": 17.476821431166,
        "set_local": 17.739026911053,
        "azimuth_rise": 96.242086753282,
        "GSTs": 4.618015588543,
        "GSTr": 17.476821431166,
        "transit_ut": 1.5517878339817E9,
        "transit": 12.176106019167,
        "raise": 6.6282530456618,
        "set_ut": 1.5518078604969E9,
        "transit_height": 32.366908597329
      },
      "dec": -6.0242450863769,
      "constell": "Aqr",
      "timezone": "Europe/London",
      "hlat": "n.a.",
      "hlong": "n.a.",
      "elongation": 0,
      "lastdate": "2019-Mar-05 00:00",
      "hx": 0,
      "ar": 23.060617283951,
      "hy": 0,
      "mag": "-26.76",
      "hlongRad": null,
      "hz": 0,
      "utc_time": 1551816600,
      "distearth": 1.4838474994878E8,
      "name": "Sun",
      "sot": 0,
      "id": "sun",
      "category": "planets",
      "hlatRad": null,
      "status": true
    }
  },
  "target": "sun"
}
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: Correct @BasilBourque ... This was just meant to be a quick and dirty example to show how to get the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Below you can find the code on how to do this in python. There are numerous ways to incorporate the code in an app. Just for illustration I casted the results in a pandas dataframe so you could view the results. I also added some code to deal with proxy settings, if this is not so, you could leave it out and simply get the url text with the requests package.

Hope it helps.

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

username = 'userID'  # ex. ID
password = "password!"  # password

dataURL = "https://theskylive.com/moon-info"

proxies = {
    'https':  'https://{}:{}@proxy:port'.format(username, password)}
proxy = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

with urllib.request.urlopen(dataURL) as url:
    text = str(url.read())

tableStart = text.find('The Moon Ephemeris')
tableEnd = text.find('Distance of The Moon from Earth')
tableProgress = tableStart

findSTR = 'moon&date='
loc = text.find(findSTR,tableStart,tableEnd)
startDate = text[loc+len(findSTR):loc+len(findSTR)+10] 

table = []
tableRow = []
counter = 0
counter2 = 0

diff = [20,4]

while loc>0:

    loc1 = text.find('<td class="desktop">',tableProgress,tableEnd)
    loc2 = text.find('<td>',tableProgress,tableEnd)

    if loc1<0:
        if loc2<0:
            loc = -1
        else:
            loc = loc2
            pos = 1
    else:
        if loc2<0:
            loc = loc1
            pos = 0
        else:            
            loc = np.min([loc1,loc2])
            pos = np.argmin([loc1,loc2])


    if loc>0:



        locStart = loc+diff[pos]
        loc = text.find('</td>',loc,tableEnd)

        if loc>0:
            extractedText = text[locStart:loc]

            if counter ==1:

                extractedText = extractedText.replace('&deg;',' deg')
                extractedText = extractedText.replace('&rsquo;',' min')
                extractedText = extractedText.replace('&rdquo;',' sec')
            elif counter ==3:                
                extractedText = extractedText.replace('&rdquo;',' arcsec')
            tableRow = tableRow+ [extractedText]
            tableProgress = loc


            counter = counter+1
            if counter==5:
                counter2 = counter2+1                
                counter = 0
                table = table+[tableRow]
                tableRow = []


idx = pd.date_range(start='2019-02-26', periods=len(table), freq='D')
cols = ['Right Ascension','Declination','Magnitude','Apparent Diameter','Constellation']

Data = pd.DataFrame(table,index=idx,columns=cols)
print(Data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instead setting up your own data scraping server you could use IFTTT for getting the data and storeing it at first.

Here are some nice tutorials: https://public.tableau.com/en-us/s/blog/2013/08/data-scraping-part-i-ifttt

Im sure you don't want your app to do the scraping.
After you got it stored you can further manipulate it with whatever language and provide it in e.g. json format as a cacheable datasource for your app.